# Is constant polling the way Aurelia's change detection is working?

Tags: aurelia

I got div with if.bind working as was suggested in this question: [Using literal JavaScript values in an Aurelia view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012855/using-literal-javascript-values-in-an-aurelia-view). But then I noticed that showTemplate on viewModel is being constantly checked by framework, about 10 times per second. The stack is following:

```
execute._prototypeProperties.visible.get (welcome.js:29)
getValue (dirty-checking.js:93)
isDirty (dirty-checking.js:127)
check (dirty-checking.js:63)
(anonymous function) (dirty-checking.js:49)
```

Is it supposed to be like this? Seems to be not very resource-friendly.

Best regards, Eugene.

Comment: [Info on how Aurelia's change detection works](http://www.danyow.net/aurelia-property-observation/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurelia uses `Object.observe` for simple Javascript properties. If `showTemplate` is a function or a getter/setter, then Aurelia currently reverts to dirty checking. This can be removed by declaring the dependencies of the function. This is outlined here: https://github.com/aurelia/binding/pull/41

I have created a version of the Aurelia Skeleton project that implements this: https://github.com/ashleygrant/skeleton-navigation/tree/declare_dependencies

To implement this, you must switch to using the `aurelia-main` attribute. Add a `main.js` file:

```
import {LogManager} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ConsoleAppender} from 'aurelia-logging-console';
import {ComputedObservationAdapter, ObjectObservationAdapter} from 'aurelia-framework';

LogManager.addAppender(new ConsoleAppender());
LogManager.setLevel(LogManager.levels.debug);

export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .defaultBindingLanguage()
    .defaultResources()
    .router()
    .eventAggregator();

    aurelia.container
      .registerSingleton(ObjectObservationAdapter, ComputedObservationAdapter);

  aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot('app', document.body));
}
```

Then, in `welcome.js`, add the following import statement:

`import {declarePropertyDependencies} from 'aurelia-framework';`

and then outside the `Welcome` class, add the following method call:

`declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['firstName', 'lastName']);`

Comment: Note, the 'aurelia-main' attribute is deprecated. You now just use aurelia-app with a value: http://blog.durandal.io/2015/03/25/aurelia-0-10-0-release-status/