# In Aurelia computeds, when setting dependencies, how would declare a dependency on an object property

Tags: javascript, aurelia

When you set up the an Aurelia computed property you can declare dependencies to avoid polling (see: [Is constant polling the way Aurelia's change detection is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028354/is-constant-polling-the-way-aurelias-change-detection-is-working)).

```
   get fullName(){
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    } 
}

declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['firstName', 'lastName']);
```

But, how would you do this if you want to use the values from properties of an object?

```
this.person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' }

get fullName(){
   return `${this.person.firstName} ${this.person.lastName}`;
}
```

This displays fine, of course, but declaring the dependencies as per below for the computed does not trigger an update when you change the value of person.firstName or person.lastName:

```
declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['person.firstName', 'person.lastName']);
```

Nor this:

```
declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['person']);
```

Is this possible with the current declareDependencies code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated Answer

This is now supported. The dependency strings no longer need to be simple property access expressions (eg `['firstName', 'lastName']`). Anything that would work in a binding expression will also work in `declarePropertyDependencies`. Examples:

- `declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['person.firstName', 'person.lastName']);`
- `declarePropertyDependencies(Welcome, 'fullName', ['person.foo().bar[baz], 'x.y.z()']);`

---

## Original Answer

This scenario is not currently supported with `declarePropertyDependencies`.  You could use Aurelia's ObserverLocator class directly or create a class that wraps it like this:

multi-observer.js

```javascript
import {ObserverLocator} from 'aurelia-framework'; // or 'aurelia-binding'

export class MultiObserver {  
  static inject() { return [ObserverLocator]; }
  constructor(observerLocator) {
    this.observerLocator = observerLocator;
  }

  observe(properties, callback) {
    var subscriptions = [], i = properties.length, object, propertyName;
    while(i--) {
      object = properties[i][0];
      propertyName = properties[i][1];
      subscriptions.push(this.observerLocator.getObserver(object, propertyName).subscribe(callback));
    }

    // return dispose function
    return () => {
      while(subscriptions.length) {
        subscriptions.pop()();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

welcome.js

```javascript
import {MultiObserver} from 'multi-observer';

export class Welcome {  
  static inject() { return [MultiObserver]; }
  constructor(multiObserver) {    
    this.person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' };    
    this.updateFullName();

    // update fullName when person.firstName/lastName changes. 
    this.dispose = multiObserver.observe(
      [[person, 'firstName'],
       [person, 'lastName']],
      () => this.updateFullName());
  }

  updateFullName() {
    this.fullName = `${this.person.firstName} {this.person.lastName}`;
  }

  deactivate() {
    this.dispose();
  }
}
```

More info [here](http://www.danyow.net/aurelia-property-observation/).  Future versions of Aurelia will include more APIs and docs in support of these common object observation scenarios.

If you only need to display the computed value the solution is much simpler- do this in your view:

```
<template>
  Full Name:  ${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}
</template>
```

I don't think this is what you're asking, but just in case...

Comment: guess you need to update the answer since latest Aurelia support this feature natively.

Comment: @huocp thanks for letting me know this was out of date.